# Create a dataset in BigQuery with Python | Receiving TypeError

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am brand new to programming so here it goes.

**My goal**: Create a dataset in an existing project in BigQuery (using python rather than UI)

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) show how to do this:

**My code**:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="apikey.json"

# Construct BigQuery client object
client = bigquery.Client    

# Set dataset_id
dataset_id = 'myProject.myDataset'

# Construct a full Dataset object to send to the API.
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id)

# Specify the geographic location
dataset.location = "US"

# # Send the dataset to the API for creation, with an explicit timeout. 
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset, timeout=30)  # Make an API request.
print("Created dataset")
```

**My error:** `TypeError: Client.create_dataset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataset'`

I refer to the relevant documentation [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_create_dataset) below

but I'm struggling to understand **how that first positional argument should look**. Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the script and it worked well :

```py
def create_dataset():
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    project_id = "{project_id}"
    dataset_id = f"{project_id}.mazlum_dataset_test"

    # Construct a full Dataset object to send to the API.
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id)

    # TODO(developer): Specify the geographic location where the dataset should reside.
    dataset.location = "EU"

    # Send the dataset to the API for creation, with an explicit timeout.
    # Raises google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict if the Dataset already
    # exists within the project.
    dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset, timeout=30)  # Make an API request.
    print("Created dataset {}.{}".format(project_id, dataset.dataset_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_dataset()
```

Your script seems to be correct.

You have to check if you are used the correct `Python` [package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) in your virtual env :

`requirements.txt` file :

```
google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.1
```

To check if your virtual env was correctly created, enter this command :

```bash
which python3
```

It should display the `python` path in the virtual env.

Launch the following command to install the package in your virtual env :

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```